# Brightness control not working on IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 (amdgpu)

Tags: linux, debian, amd-graphics, brightness, backlight

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 with a fresh Debian Bullseye installation. Unfortunately the screen brightness control doesn't work out of the box.

lspci lists the following video device:

```
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I've already found various suggestions on the Internet, including boot options like `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux` or `amdgpu.backlight=0`. None of those worked.

How do I get the brightness control keys to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IdeaPad 3 17ABA7 seems to come with the AMD Ryzen 5625U CPU+GPU which uses the `amdgpu` driver. However, this driver needs a proprietary firmware to be able to control the screen brightness. Debian doesn't come with this firmware by default. To install it, add a `non-free` source to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, run `apt update` and then `apt install firmware-amd-graphics`. Afterwards a simple reboot should be enough to enable the screen brightness control via keyboard.

*Don't* set any of the mentioned boot options from your question. They are not necessary and might even prevent the screen control from working properly.

You can check which video driver you are currently using by running `lshw -c video`. The output contains a line starting with `configuration:`, it should contain `driver=amdgpu`.